# Is there an arbitary limit on the size of vectors you can put into session.run?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I recently started learning tensorflow, I was doing the first tutorial on tensorflow website and I encountered a problem.

I am using tensorflow on Cloud 9.

The starting code has no problems:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784]);
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]));
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]));

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b);

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10]);
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y));

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy);

init = tf.initialize_all_variables();

xs = mnist.train.images;
ys = mnist.train.labels;

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1));
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

sess = tf.Session();
sess.run(init);
```

In the training part of the tutorial, it says it is faster to get batches of 100 images from the whole training set of 55000 images. The code for that is:

```
for i in range(1000):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
  print str(i) + " -> " + str(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}));
```

This works and I get the %91 accuracy as the tutorial says.

Then I tried to send the whole set into training as the tutorial suggested was computationally expensive. I kept the iterations low to see what actually happens.

```
for i in range(100):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys});
    print str(i) + " -> " + str(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}));
```

However, whatever the number of iterations I always got 0.098 accuracy.

Then I tried another way to achieve the same result.

```
for i in range(100):
    for start, end in zip(range(0,len(xs),50), range(50, len(ys), 50)):
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {x: xs[start:end], y_: ys[start:end]});
    print str(i) + " -> " + str(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}));
```

In this example, it iterates over the whole set 50 by 50. And this method works up to 200 by 200. After 200, whatever the number is I get 0.098 accuracy.

So as I understand there is an arbitary limit on the number of items you can send into training. Is is true or am I missing something here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no limit on number of examples, but learning rate (`0.01` in your case) interacts with batch size. If you make your batch size 10x larger, your gradients are 10x larger and you take 10x longer steps. This can end up overshooting and increasing your objective at each step instead of decreasing it. You need to tune your learning rate (try diving by square root of batch size multiplier), or use an adaptive descent method (`AdamOptimizer` will automatically adjust learning rate over time)